# how do I set key as null in when using sftp csv connector in kafka. I need this to distribute the records in round robin manner across brokers

Tags: apache-kafka, sftp, apache-kafka-connect

This is the configuration I am using for my csv source connector. This is producing key as "{}" an empty struct. I think this is causing all the messages to accumulate in one partition.

```
    "name": "NdpiSourceConnector_csv_1",
    "config": {
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.sftp.SftpCsvSourceConnector",
        "cleanup.policy":"MOVE",
        "behavior.on.error":"IGNORE",
        "input.path": "/home/******/Desktop/ndpi/drop",
        "error.path": "/home/******/Desktop/ndpi/error",
        "finished.path": "/home/shyena/Desktop/ndpi/processed",
        "input.file.pattern": ".*\\.csv",
        "sftp.username":"********",
        "sftp.password":"**********",
        "sftp.host":"**************",
        "sftp.port":22,
        "kafka.topic": "NdpiSourceTopic1",
        "csv.first.row.as.header": "true",
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "key.converter.schemas.enable":"false",
        "key.schema":"{\"type\":\"STRUCT\",\"name\":\"FlowRecord\",\"isOptional\":\"true\",\"fieldSchemas\":{}}",
        "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "value.schema": "{\"type\":\"STRUCT\",\"name\":\"FlowRecord\",\"fieldSchemas\":{\"flow_id\":{\"type\":\"STRING\"},\"protocol\":{\"type\":\"STRING\"},\"first_seen\":{\"type\":\"STRING\"},\"last_seen\":{\"type\":\"STRING\"},\"duration\":{\"type\":\"STRING\"},\"src_ip\":{\"type\":\"STRING\"},\"src_port\":{\"type\":\"STRING\"},\"dst_ip\":{\"type\":\"STRING\"},\"dst_port\":{\"type\":\"STRING\"}}}",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable":"false"
    }
  }
```

From the docs I came to know that passing a null value to key will distribute the records in RR. when I try to insert records using a python script without specifying the key, the records are being distributed in round robin.

what is that I need to do when using connector to get the same results, please help me out.

Comment: null key does not roundrobin the records. See docs on `StickyPartitioner`

Answer (score 0):

To set the key to `null` (and let the producer Partitioner does its job with the null keys), you can add an SMT to your connector:

```
// Add the following SMT configuration
"transforms": "setKeyToNull",
"transforms.setKeyToNull.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ReplaceField$Key",
"transforms.setKeyToNull.blacklist": ".*"
```